# Joinpoint VS ProceedingJoinPoint in AOP using aspectJ?

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

Can any one tell me what is the difference between `Joinpoint` and  `Proceedingjoinpoint`?

When to use `Joinpoint` and `Proceedingjoinpoint` in the method of aspect class?

I used the `JoinPoint` in my AspectJ class like:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.pointel.aop.test1.AopTest.beforeAspect(..))")  
public void adviceChild(){}  

@Before("adviceChild()")  
public void beforeAdvicing(JoinPoint joinPoint /*,ProceedingJoinPoint pjp - used refer book marks of AOP*/){ 

    //Used to get the parameters of the method !
    Object[] arguments = joinPoint.getArgs();
    for (Object object : arguments) {
        System.out.println("List of parameters : " + object);
    }

    System.out.println("Method name : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    log.info("beforeAdvicing...........****************...........");
    log.info("Method name : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    System.out.println("************************"); 
}
```

But what I see in other resources is:

```
@Around("execution(* com.mumz.test.spring.aop.BookShelf.addBook(..))")
public void aroundAddAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp){
    Object[] arguments = pjp.getArgs();
    for (Object object : arguments) {
        System.out.println("Book being added is : " + object);
    }
    try {
        pjp.proceed();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here what will `ProceedingJoinPoint` do differently compare to 'JointPoint`? Also what will`pjp.proceed()` do for us?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
@Around("execution(* com.mumz.test.spring.aop.BookShelf.addBook(..))")
```

It means before calling `com.mumz.test.spring.aop.BookShelf.addBook` method  `aroundAddAdvice`  method is called.
After 
`System.out.println("Book being added is : " + object);` operation is completed . it will call your actual method `addBook()`. `pjp.proceed()` will call `addBook()` method.

Comment: Thans for your reply.. So Are you saying the `pjp.proceed()` will call the `addBook()` method twice ?

Comment: No, first it will call aroundAddAdvice method.Then it will call addBook().

Comment: You can see it by debugging.

Comment: So What is the difference between the `Joinpoint` and `Proceedingjoinpoint` ?

Comment: .If you use before,after-throwing,after-returning and after use Jointpoint.If you  use around use Proceedingjoinpoint  .They are just interface.Proceedingjoinpoint  is extending Joinpoint .So,seeing its functionality you can select as per urs requirement which to use.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27470/discussion-between-anand-and-abishkar)

Answer (score 33):

An around advice is a special advice that can control when and if a method (or other join point) is executed. This is true for around advices only, so they require an argument of type `ProceedingJoinPoint`, whereas other advices just use a plain `JoinPoint`. A sample use case is to cache return values:

```
private SomeCache cache;

@Around("some.signature.pattern.*(*)")
public Object cacheMethodReturn(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp){
    Object cached = cache.get(pjp.getArgs());
    if(cached != null) return cached; // method is never executed at all
    else{
        Object result = pjp.proceed();
        cache.put(pjp.getArgs(), result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

In this code (using a non-existent cache technology to illustrate a point) the actual method is only called if the cache doesn't return a result. This is the exact way the [Spring EHCache Annotations](https://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/) project works, for example.

Another specialty of around advices is that they must have a return value, whereas other advice types must not have one.

Comment: Thanks for your golden answer...One more doubt. `How to get the input parameters of a method and the return value of the same method using the @Around using the ProceedingJoinPoint ?`

Comment: See my code above: the input parameters can be retrieved through `pjp.getArgs()`, the method return value through `pjp.proceed()`

Comment: Lets click the link for chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27495/room-for-anand-and-sean-patrick-floyd

Comment: @Anand I don't have the time to chat here. look at my profile and contact me though skype or fb chat

Answer (score 4):

Use **JoinPoint** with following advice types:

```
 @Before, @After, @AfterReturning, @AfterThrowing
```

Use **ProceedingJoinPoint** with following advice type:

```
@Around
```

Answer (score 0):

`ProceedingJoinPoint` is a `JoinPoint` with additional features.

`ProceedingJoinPoint` is used with `@Around` advice. `@Around` is very powerful advice that combines the features of rest of the Advice.

`ProceedingJoinPoint::proceed` is basically used to execute the original method.

Consider following example:

```
@Around("@annotation(com.annotations.ExecutionLoggerAround)")
public void executeLogger(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Method execution starts at :: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
    System.out.println("Method execution completes at :: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
}

@ExecutionLoggerAround
public void generateReport() {
    System.out.println("Generating XLS report !!");
}

public @interface ExecutionLogger {
}
```

Now when you will call `generateReport`, `Around` advice will be executed. If you skip line `proceedingJoinPoint.proceed()`, the actual method will not be executed. You will see only those two `println` in the console.

PS: To understand better you need to know how AOP works. Spring creates proxy objects either using JDK proxy or CGLIB proxy. So its actually the proxied object that executes at runtime which use our method behind the scene.

I have written more about this [here](https://medium.com/@yogendra.209/custom-redis-cache-using-spring-aop-d04b49756a8f)